# RoR and Ajax: How can I make my Ajax request work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm tying to do an Ajax request on a delete method for active storage files so my page won't reload.

I have two controllers: 'project_steps' (i'm using wicked gem) and 'projects'.

**My view: project_steps/fourth_step.html.erb**

```
<% if @project.supporting_docs.attached? %>
  <div id="remove_file">
    <%= render partial: "existing_files", :locals => {project: @project} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**My partial: project_steps/_existing_files.html.erb**

```
<% @project.supporting_docs.each do |file| %>
  blah blah
  <%= link_to 'Remove', delete_file_attachment_project_url(file.signed_id),
     method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

**My projects_controller:**

```
def delete_file_attachment
     file = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])
     file.attachments.first.purge
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js
     end
   end
```

**projects/delete_file_attachment.js.erb:**

```
$('#remove_file').html("<%= j render(partial: 'project_steps/existing_files', :locals => 
     {project: @project}) %>")
```

**My Routes:**

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    delete :delete_file_attachment
  end
end

scope 'projects/:project_id' do
  resources :project_steps
end
```

**My Error**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `supporting_docs' for nil:NilClass):
    3:     <strong>You have attached the following files:</strong>
    4:   </div>
    5:   <br>
    6:   <% @project.supporting_docs.each do |file| %>
    7:     <div class="row">
    8:       <div class="col">
```

My delete works fine and I see why the error is there but i'm wondering how can I make Ajax work and what i'm doing wrong?  Happy to provide as much code as needed! Ty.

P.S if anyone would like to suggest a solution other than going through partial you feel might be better by all means!

Answer (score 0):

When using partials with locals, you access the variable without the `@`, i.e. to access the variable in `project_steps/_existing_files.html.erb` you need to use `project` instead of `@project`:

**project_steps/_existing_files.html.erb**

```
<% project.supporting_docs.each do |file| %>
  blah blah
  <%= link_to 'Remove', delete_file_attachment_project_url(file.signed_id),
     method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

Please also note that using `@project` in your `projects/delete_file_attachment.js.erb` doesn't work if you don't set the `@project` variable in the controller action `delete_file_attachment`, i.e. you'd probably need to add a line along `@project = Project.find ...` to your `delete_file_attachment` method.

See the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) guide for more informations about using locals in partials.

Comment: Thanks! I know i'm close but when I try to define @project = Project.find(params[:id]) in the action or in my before_action it tries to set the project id as the blob signed_id? ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcE1CIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6e3554cd4999501042c32eba11dac2ded007c63a):

Comment: Because that what you're passing in in the delete_file_attachment_project_url(file.signed_id) method call in your view. Your application expects the ID of the project in the URL helper, as the definition in your routes.rb file creates an URL like:

/projects/:id/delete_file_attachment

where the :id Param is the ID of the project.

You could try:

delete_file_attachment_project_url(project.id, file: file.signed_id)

That would generate an URL like:

/projects/<project.id>/delete_file_attachment?file=<file.signed_id>

and you could access both IDs. Or maybe rethink your routes.